# Batch/Bulk rename of folders/directories with wildcards [windows or linux]

Tags: cmd, rename, wildcard, bulk

Hello I have a directory for my photos in the structure of

Pictures/year/month/[dd/mm/yyyy]_description.

Sometimes I did not use [dd/mm/yyyy] but [dd/mm/yy] for example [22-03-13] instead [22-03-2013].

I need to rename all of this with a command because there are a lot to change it by hand.

I was able to find them by using "Everything" finder with the

> "E:\Pictures\" [??-??-13]_*

I would love a command like:

> rename [??-??-13]_* to [??-??-2013]_*

where ? and * remain the same. Is this possible? Thank you very much for your time.

PS I can use either Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many linux distros come with a great tool called [rename](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename-1.9/bin/rename.PL) that does just what you want.

For example:

```
$ rename -n 's/(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})_(.*)/$1-$2-20$3_$4/' ./*
'./08-01-14_tahiti.jpg' would be renamed to './08-01-2014_tahiti.jpg'
'./14-11-13_guam.jpg' would be renamed to './14-11-2013_guam.jpg'
'./23-07-12_hawaii.jpg' would be renamed to './23-07-2012_hawaii.jpg'
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I managed to search and find the folders with "find". But I can not understand how to rename it. I read the man but my case is a bit complicated and I did not manage to make it. Any help? :)

Comment: Updated. Does the example help?

Comment: Yes I get it now! I tried it in a test folder and it worked out. As I read this is perl lang? Thank you for your example!

This is exactly how it worked out. Of course if you need to make the changes you have to remove -n.
rename -n 's/(\[)(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})(\])_(.*)/$1$2-$3-20$4$5_$6/' ./*

Comment: I tried to apply it in the main folder but it couldn't reach the sub directories so i found this one

`shopt -s globstar` 
before hiting the rename and I changed the `./*` to `**` That worked to all directories but it was searching in files also. I think that if I have put the $ at the end of the (]) it will not made this.! Anyway. I made it thanks to you! God bless you!!  :)